# trigger on chatter when a content is created in libraray

Tags: trigger, chatter

I want to write a trigger to insert a feed in chatter which could be a link to the library  when I create a content in a library.{ Link to the content in the library preferably .But even a link to the library will do}

```
trigger ContentVersionTrigger on ContentVersion (after insert) 
{ 
   ContentVersion[] cv=Trigger.new; 
   InsertToChatter.InsertContent(cv); 
} 


public class InsertToChatter
{ 
   public static void Insertcontent (ContentVersion[] cv) 
   { 
     FeedItem post = new FeedItem(); post.Body = 'New file has been created.Pls check link'; 
     post.LinkUrl= URL('cs18.salesforce.com/sfc/#version?selectedDocumentId='+ cv.ContentDocumentId' ;
     insert post; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a trigger on **ContentDocument** SObject on after insert event to get the Id of the document and create a **FeedItem** record with a link to your ContentDocument (/sfc/#version?selectedDocumentId=yourDocumentId)

Give it a try and post your code here if you need help with it

Comment: I have written something but I am completely new to this and hence there might be a lot of errors. Pls help:
trigger ContentVersionTrigger on ContentVersion (after insert) {
    ContentVersion[] cv=Trigger.new;
     
        InsertToChatter.InsertContent(cv)
     
}

public class InsertToChatter{


public static void Insertcontent (ContentVersion[] cv)
{

FeedItem post = new FeedItem();

post.Body = 'New file has been created.Pls check link';

post.LinkUrl= URL('https://cs18.salesforce.com/sfc/#version?selectedDocumentId='+ cv.ContentDocumentId'

insert post;
}

}

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot answer the question myself within 8 hours of poating and hence i had to write a comment . The spacing has gone for a toss and code appears cluttered. Sorry

Comment: I updated you question with your code, I don't think this will work as you expected. first the trigger must be on ContentDocument and not ContentVersion? what are the errors you're getting?

Comment: I thot since a version is more specific than a document..It showss an error for the url.I cannot save it to the post url.The error is : Compile Error: line breaks not allowed in string literals at line 7 column -1 for this line post.LinkUrl= URL(cs18.salesforce.com/sfc/#version?selectedDocumentId='+ cv.ContentDocumentId) ;

Comment: If I do this:                                                string s = 'cs18.salesforce.com/sfc/#versionselectedDocumentId='+ cv.ContentDocumentId;
     post.LinkUrl= URL(s) ;...........error is  Compile Error:Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: LIST<ContentVersion> at line 6 column 73

Comment: Can you update your question by adding your code and the errors?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried writting trigger on ContentDocument. It is working as of now..

Here it is the code :-

```
trigger PublishlinkOnChatter on ContentDocument (After insert,After Update) {
    list<FeedItem> lst=new List<feedItem>();
    for(ContentDocument cd:trigger.new){
            FeedItem fi= new FeedItem();
            fi.LinkUrl='https://na15.salesforce.com/'+cd.LatestPublishedVersionId;
            fi.parentid=userinfo.getUserID();
            fi.body='Modified the Content';
            lst.add(fi);


        }
        insert lst;
}
```